# rails server can't function on windows 7 missing json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

When I want to installing the ruby on rails on my windows 7, I have faced some problems.

#### 1. When I start the rails server.

The error messages: Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems

#### 2. Then I run the 'bundle install'.

The error messages: InstallError: the 'json' native gem requires installed build tools.

#### 3. The cmd asking me to install json 1.8.3 also get error.(gem install json -v '1.8.3')

The error messages: While executing gem ... OptionParser::MissingArgument
missing argument:-v

#### do anyone faced same problem at here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in the gemfile:

```
gem 'json', '~> 1.8.3'
```

And the `bundle install` in the terminal.